# Possible of using Typescript to infer object keys from static strings (either Enum or Object)

Tags: typescript, url-routing

Say I want to build some routes

```js
enum Routes {
    profile: '/user/:username'
}
```

I'd like to be able to extract a key of `username` for inferred usage in a routing function. e.g.

```js
// example of ideal usage, open to other functionally similar patterns

goToRoute <Routes.profile> ({ username: /* <- TS extracts the param and suggests the key for us */ })

// => '/user/<VALUE_PASSED>'
```

is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

How about this...

[image]

```
const routes = {
  "/user": ["username"]
} as const;

type Routes = typeof routes;
type RoutePrefix = keyof Routes;
type RouteParams = Routes[RoutePrefix][number];

type RouteParamMap<RoutePrefix> = {
  [K in RouteParams]:string;
}

function goToRoute<RoutePrefix>(route:RoutePrefix, params:RouteParamMap<RoutePrefix>){

}

goToRoute("/user", {
  username:"cefn"
})
```

Comment: Hi cefn! Firstly, thanks for taking the time to answer.

How would your solution looks for multiple (separate) params? i.e. `/user/:username/posts/:postId`? I worry about the level of abstraction becoming more and more less readable as simply a static route